# Distribute an Android library built with Gradle

Tags: android, github, gradle, android-studio

For a summer project I'm working on a schedule application. Because I wasn't able to find a calendar-like `AdapterView`, I started building one myself ([In progress result](http://marijnvdwerf.nl/u/1373210869.png)). Though still in progress, I'd like to share this `ScheduleView` as a library on GitHub, but I'm not sure how I should structure my Android Studio project so it contains the source and an example implementation, and other people can require it easily.

Answer (score 1):

You should take as example another project.

[Android Menu-Drawer](https://github.com/SimonVT/android-menudrawer), for example, has a simple and easy to understand project structure :

- menudrawer [library module]
- menudrawer-samples [samples module]

And other files related to gradle and the project :

- .gitignore
- LICENSE
- README.md
- build.gradle
- settings.gradle